# Quill mention plugin not working on IE browser

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer, quill

I am using [quill mention](https://github.com/afconsult/quill-mention) plugin with quill editor with Angular 7 app. This is working fine in chrome and other latest browsers. However when I ran this on IE it failed as shown in image.

[image]

When I clone this project and ran its provided sample it is working fine on IE when ran separately. I added all required polyfills in angular. All application running smoothly and this plugin not transforming itself. Babel configuration has been setup in it. However not working in app.

Update basically this module is es5 with js extension. So I read on google that typescript only compiles ts related file in node_modules. Is it possible to compile it also.

Need help

Comment: Can you please inform us which errors it is showing in the console? Picture of a code will not help to get the idea about the issue. If possible than please try to provide your sample code which hows how you integrate this plug in with Angular 7. If plugin is working with IE separately than it can be possible that something wrong with your code. I find that other users also have similar kind of issue with this plugin in IE. Ref: https://github.com/afconsult/quill-mention/issues/72

Comment: It is writtern Syntax error on such line. Basically this module is written on es6 .js extension. So typescript not compiling it.

Comment: It is better to contact the developers of Quill to check whether there is any way to solve or work around this issue for Internet Explorer or not.